# How to parse .xsd file using XSOMParser

Tags: java, xsd, xsom

I need to parse below XSD file..  and I have to read all the values..

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="urn:books"
        xmlns:bks="urn:books">

<xsd:complexType name="Book1">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


</xsd:schema>
```

Please let me know how can I do it using "XSOMParser".

Comment: Why are you using XSOM?  It's a peculiar and highly-specialised tool.  Can't you just use a normal XML parser?

Comment: Check out this blog [XSOM Tutorial](http://myjavastuffs.blogspot.com/2011/09/xml-schema-document-parsing-using-xsom.html)

Answer (score 1):

What code have you tried?

Start off with the examples from the [XSOM user guide:](http://xsom.java.net/userguide.html)

```
import com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser;
import com.sun.xml.xsom.XSSchemaSet;

XSOMParser parser = new XSOMParser();
parser.setErrorHandler(...);
parser.setEntityResolver(...);

parser.parseSchema( new File("myschema.xsd"));
parser.parseSchema( new File("XHTML.xsd"));

XSSchemaSet sset = parser.getResult();
```

and further down in the user guide:

> For example, the following code lists all the global element declarations and whether they are abstract or not.

```
// iterate each XSSchema object. XSSchema is a per-namespace schema.
Iterator itr = sset.iterateSchema();
while( itr.hasNext() ) {
  XSSchema s = (XSSchema)itr.next();

  System.out.println("Target namespace: "+s.getTargetNamespace());

  Iterator jtr = s.iterateElementDecls();
  while( jtr.hasNext() ) {
    XSElementDecl e = (XSElementDecl)jtr.next();

    System.out.print( e.getName() );
    if( e.isAbstract() )
      System.out.print(" (abstract)");
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```